# Networkit graphEvent (python)

Tags: python, graph, network-analysis, networkit

Another Networkit question. Seems like this module doesn't get much support (and I certainly don't want to open issues on github just to get help), but you don't get if you don't ask. By reading the docs it seems like there's a lot of functions to perform certain operations in an optimal way... but often I just don't get how to do use those functions.

This time I am trying to understand what a GraphEvent is. Let's say that I build a graph, I calculate the connected components and then I remove edges and nodes iteratively, based on some condition; then I want to calculate the connected components again. I thought that I could do something like:

```
cc=components.DynConnectedComponents(G)
cc.run()
...
#edge removals
...
cc.update()
```

but `components.DynConnectedComponents(Graph).update(GraphEvent)`, which updates the connected components after an event... well it requires a GraphEvent object, and I haven't the slightest idea of what it might be and how to handle it. There's nothing in the docs that clarifies it and I would appreciate a lot if someone could explain me this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received an answer to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49319722/usage-of-foredges-iterator-in-networkit-python/49340771#49340771) where the graphEvent is explained too.